# Pandas/Pyspark - How to melt multiple variable and value columns into one variable and one value column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have the following table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'metric_1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
    'value_1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
    'metric_2': {0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'z'},
    'value_2': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6},
    'metric_3': {0: 'j', 1: 'k', 2: 'l'},
    'value_3': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9}
})
```

[image]

I am trying to melt the table so it looks like this instead:

[image]

I have tried using melt as follows:

```
 pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=['metric_1', 'metric_2', 'metric_3'],
    value_vars=['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']
)
```

but end up something completely different.

Thank you in advance for any help I may receive on this. I'm also open to solutions via Pyspark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.wide_to_long`, you are trying to do simultaneous melting:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['metric', 'value'], 'index', 'No', '_', '\d+')
```

Output:

```
         metric  value
index No              
0     1       a      1
1     1       b      3
2     1       c      5
0     2       x      2
1     2       y      4
2     2       z      6
0     3       j      7
1     3       k      8
2     3       l      9
```

Comment: `\d+` is the default suffix, so it's not really needed here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stack` with some column manipulation.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
df.stack() # .sort_index(level=1) if you care about that

    metric  value
0 1      a      1
  2      x      2
  3      j      7
1 1      b      3
  2      y      4
  3      k      8
2 1      c      5
  2      z      6
  3      l      9
```